# Can only change the first cells image in a UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I am trying to fill a collectionView with images that I have stored in an array. This is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    let img = poiImages.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage
    cell.assignImage(img!)

    return cell
}
```

The background colours change properly and I did this as an initial test to verify that the method was working. However, I can only assign an image for the first cell. All cells thereafter are left blank, but still have a black/orange colour assigned to them.

This is my custom class code for the UICollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView!.frame = frame
        imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill // maybe change to fit
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(imageView!)
    }

    func assignImage(img: UIImage) {
        imageView!.image = img
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and in the initialiser for my view which the collection view is embedded in I remembered to put:

```
poiImageView.registerClass(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

I feel like I am somehow only making one instance of my custom class.

Any ideas?

Thanks a million

### EDIT

Still can't get it to work and still looking for an answer. I can't think of any reason for this to happen. Has anyone experienced the same?

Comment: Did you check if `poiImages` array has images and does not return `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that and all seemed good. Also to make sure that this wasn't the root of the problem I stuck in a static image so that I knew it was there. Once again only the first cell was updated. I'm so confused haha

Comment: This may not be source of problem, but you should put `super.init(frame: frame)` at the beginning of your overridden `init(frame:_)` method. Also did you check in view debugger or via LLDB if there is anything in `image` property of `imageView` of your cell?

Comment: Hi. I only put the code before init(frame:_) as a final attempt to resolve the problem. I've put it back and the problem persists. I also checked with LLDB and the imageview does have an image set.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as well. only the first cell gets updated. any solution?

Comment: Hi Ng. Sorry I never managed to find a solution and have since left the work alone. I hope someone else can give you some direction

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still interested but pretty sure all you need to do is change

```
imageView!.frame = frame
```

to

```
imageView!.frame = bounds
```

and you should be golden. It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

`indexPath.row` is for `UITableView`

`indexPath.item` is for `UICollectionView`

Comment: I thought using .row seemed odd. I've switched it but unfortunately that doesn't fix my bigger problem. Cheers for the input though.